# Browser Switch Plugin for Visual Studio 2013 +NuGet

Tags: javascript, plugins, browser, visual-studio-2013

I am looking for a Plugin which helps me to run the application in selected browser(IE, FireFox, Chrome..) mode from visual studio 2013. Do we have any plugin like that in NuGet Package ?

And also I am looking for plugin which shows the javascript error when compiled the application in VisualStudio 2013, do we have anything like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature that is available in VS 2013 by default. Details available at: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

Javascript can be debugged using the steps mentioned at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/28/javascript-native-interop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Since JavaScript is an interpreted language, its not possible to show errors when you compile your application.